# c# - UserControl doesn't appear on winform if i dynamically added some controls in the code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

Hello there i have created a userControl for windows form C# and i dynamicly added some panels in the code and after running the form **My control is not appering** in the form and i removed the added controls from the code then **The Control Appear** can someone help me please ??

```
public partial class Schedual : UserControl
    {
        int days;

        public int Days
        {
            get { return days; }
            set
            {
                days = value;
                change = true;
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }

        int periods;

        public int Periods
        {
            get { return periods; }
            set
            {
                periods = value;
                change = true;
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }

        Brush brush;

        bool change;

        List<Panel> panels;

        public Schedual()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.days = 1;
            this.periods = 1;
            brush = Brushes.White;
            change = false;
            panels = new List<Panel>();
            InitFirstPanel();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the first panel on the board
        /// </summary>
        private void InitFirstPanel()
        {
            var p = new Panel();
            p.Size = this.Size;
            p.Location = this.Location;
            AddPanels(p);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a given panel to the list of panels
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="panel">the wanted panel</param>
        private void AddPanels(Panel panel)
        {
            panels.Add(panel);
            this.Controls.Add(panel);  //if i removed this then the control work
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.DrawString("Yaser", new Font("Arial", 20.5f), Brushes.Violet, new PointF(200, 150));
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            var h = this.Height / days;
            var w = this.Width / periods;
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0,0,this.Width,this.Height));
            if (change)
                panels.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i <= days; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= periods; j++)
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(brush, j * w, i * h, w, h);
                    if (change)
                    {
                        AddPanel(j * w, i * h, w, h);
                    }
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, i * h, this.Width, i * h);
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, j * w, 0, this.Height, j * w);
                    if (brush == Brushes.White)
                        brush = Brushes.YellowGreen;
                    else
                        brush = Brushes.White;
                }
            }
            change = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Panel and adds it to the list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">the x position of the panel</param>
        /// <param name="y">the y position of the panel</param>
        /// <param name="width">the width of the panel</param>
        /// <param name="height">the height position of the panel</param>
        private void AddPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            var panel = new Panel();
            panel.Location = new Point(x, y);
            panel.Size = new Size(width, height);
            AddPanels(panel);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is showing fine, the problem is that you set  `p.Size = this.Size;` inside of `InitFirstPanel` which means your gray panel will be over the whole user control after you've added it to `Controls`. Try setting different size and you will be fine :)

```
p.Size = new Size(50,50);
```

Comment: i did't and it still not working
and to be sure i removed the InitFirstPanel() function
but i did chang the color of the panel to transparent 
and the control started throwing Exception (Error Creating Window Handle) when adding it to the Controls List

Comment: @YaserJaradeh the exception is clear, because after removing the InitFirstPanel your panel is not initialized any longer. Changing color to transparent will not work as you expecting, so simply remove             one line p.Size = this.Size;